# How to fix kdenlive crashes on Ubuntu 13.10 during scene finding

Tags: ubuntu, video-editing, kdenlive

I am new to the video editing software `kdenlive` and tried to use it to edit a large ``` avi`` file. I added the ```avi`clip and started a job to find the scenes in this avi. Halfway through the clip (after 30 minutes or so),`kdenlive` suddenly crashed.

How can I fix this problem?

Additional information related to my questions will be given below once they are asked. As I have no idea whether the issue is related to Ubuntu, the desktop, kdenlive or the `avi` file, I cannot be more specific at this point.

**Additional information**

- Sometimes the program outputs the following:

  ```
  Unable to start Dr. Konqi
  ```

  But there seems to exist no package which might solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to debug issues such as this I would first run them in a shell so that you can get access to any logging messages that the tool might be throwing when it fails either before, during, or after it has crashed.

```
$ kdenlive |& tee kdenlive.log
```

From a shell. Try this and capture any output that may get generated into the file `kdenlive.log`. Going further you can use `strace` to see what system calls `kdenlive` is making which might help give you hints as to where the issue might be occurring.

```
$ strace -o kdenlive_strace.log kdenlive
```

Comment: I will do this as soon as I have the opportunity and post the relevant output (or what I think is relevant).

Comment: Sure thing. If the logs are long you can post on pastebin.com and then post the link here.